# AWS SAM YAML template - Unknown Tag !Ref

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, serverless, aws-serverless, aws-sam

When I try to deploy my AWS SAM YAML file, it fails saying the !Ref is an unknown tag.

[image]

Any ideas to get around this?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  MySimpleFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs4.3
      CodeUri: s3://<bucket>/MyCode.zip
      Events:
        MyUploadEvent:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Id: !Ref Bucket
            Events: Create
  Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
```

Comment: I think the ! notation is still not supported. Try just REF

Comment: Using !Ref in a YAML AWS SAM is definitely posssible.

Comment: @EdsonF: What's generating the error message? What's the IDE you're using?

Comment: @Dunedan Visual Studio 2017. And I've also tried Visual Studio Code, to no availe

Comment: Does it fail when you run `sls deploy`?

Comment: Exclamation mark `!` in YAML has a specific meaning (it is intended only for use locally (internal to an application). Use in communicating with other applications is not recommended.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

You can add custom YAML tags in your `settings.json`:

```json
"yaml.customTags": [
  "!Equals sequence",
  "!FindInMap sequence",
  "!GetAtt",
  "!GetAZs",
  "!ImportValue",
  "!Join sequence",
  "!Ref",
  "!Select sequence",
  "!Split sequence",
  "!Sub"
]
```

Comment: Adding this helped me. In VSCode hit ctrl+, search for _yaml custom tags_ and click on _Edit in settings.json_.

Comment: FYI, if you are using neovim with `coc-yaml`, adding this will work like a charm! Just add it into `coc-settings.json` by running `:CocConfig` <3

Comment: For [neovim-lsp](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig#yamlls), this would be a part of typical init block in lua, like this: ```require'nvim_lsp'.yamlls.setup{settings={yaml={customTags={"!Equals sequence", !FindInMap sequence", !GetAtt scalar", !GetAZs scalar", !ImportValue scalar", !Join sequence scalar", !Ref scalar", !Select sequence", !Split sequence", !Sub scalar", !And sequence", !Not sequence", !Equals sequence", !Sub sequence", !ImportValue scalar", !If sequence"}}}}
EOF```.

Comment: This solution didn't work until I disabled the kubernetes extension

Comment: For me needed click gear icon on my extension on VSCode > Extension Setting and update Custom Tag

Comment: I had this issue with `GetAtt` and needed to add `"!GetAtt sequence"` in addition to the settings that were automatically added by "update Custom Tag". (Also needed to add `"!Cidr"` and `"!Cidr sequence"`).

Comment: Cmd+Shift+P and select Open Settings UI (Ctrl+Shift+P for Windows I think)

Comment: Related: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-yaml/issues/669

Answer (score 39):

First validate your extensions, I eliminated the extension called Redhat yaml and problems solved, I have the next extensions and everything is ok.

- vscode-cfn-lint
- Serverless IDE
- aws-cloudformation-yaml
- AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio Code

Comment: removing  Redhat yaml extension worked for me

Comment: Installing AWS Toolkit VSC extension removed all errors coming from Redhat YAML extension.

Answer (score 11):

This error message is almost certainly a false-positive from the YAML parser your IDE is using. To assess the correctness of the AWS SAM template, you should use [cfn-python-lint](https://github.com/awslabs/cfn-python-lint/) instead, which comes with plugins for most major IDEs (unfortunately not for Visual Studio, but for Visual Studio Code).

Answer (score 11):

The [CloudFormation Visual Studio Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kddejong.vscode-cfn-lint) should [manage these tags for you](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cfn-lint-visual-studio-code/blob/089b197e2c7df4ec26d35c23ebb77383c724a86e/client/src/extension.ts#L57)

Answer (score 7):

On Visual Studio Code, click `File` ---> `Perferences` -----> `Settings`
On the search bar, type  `Yaml tags`,  then it will show out `Yaml:Custom Tags`
Click `Edit in settings.json`

On `settings.json` file:

```
"yaml.customTags": [
        "!Cidr",
        "!Cidr sequence",
        "!And",
        "!And sequence",
        "!If",
        "!If sequence",
        "!Not",
        "!Not sequence",
        "!Equals",
        "!Equals sequence",
        "!Or",
        "!Or sequence",
        "!FindInMap",
        "!FindInMap sequence",
        "!Base64",
        "!Join",
        "!Join sequence",
        "!Ref",
        "!Sub",
        "!Sub sequence",
        "!GetAtt",
        "!GetAZs",
        "!ImportValue",
        "!ImportValue sequence",
        "!Select",
        "!Select sequence",
        "!Split",
        "!Split sequence"
    ],
```

Note:  if you have issues with `"!Cidr"`, make sure you include the `"!Cidr sequence"` as well, the `unresolved Tag` problem will be fixed

I hope it is helpful for you!

Answer (score 5):

The Ansible extension for Visual Studio Code was causing this error message for me. I removed it, and that solved the problem for my situation.

Answer (score 5):

In vscode, click file > save workspace as > click save

Then, open workspace.code-workspace and paste the following:

```
{   
    "folders": [
      {
        "path": ".."
      }   
    ],   
    "settings": {
      "yaml.customTags": [
        "!Equals sequence",
        "!FindInMap sequence",
        "!GetAtt",
        "!GetAZs",
        "!ImportValue",
        "!Join sequence",
        "!Ref",
        "!Select sequence",
        "!Split sequence",
        "!Sub"
      ]   
    } 
}
```

Comment: I prefer this solution because it doesn't add unnecessary settings to the main `settings.json`, thank you.